# Arguments aren't sufficient instantiated

Tags: prolog, polynomials, instantiation-error

I read my code for an hour but I'm not able to understand where the problem is. I read that this error means that I use an argument I didn't instantiate before but I can't see where it is. Can you help me?

```
as_monomial(X, m(X, 0, [])) :- number(X), !.
as_monomial(^(Y, Z), m(1, Z, [v(Z, Y)])) :- !.
as_monomial(*(X, ^(Y, Z)), m(G, K, Q)) :- as_monomial(X, m(G, TD, Vars)), K is (TD + Z), ordina_m([v(Z, Y)| Vars], Q), !.
as_monomial(*(X, Y), m(G, K, Q)) :- as_monomial(X, m(G, TD, Vars)), K is (TD + 1), ordina_m([v(1, Y)| Vars], Q), !.
as_monomial(-(X), m(-A, Y, L)) :- as_monomial(X, m(A, Y, L)).
as_monomial(X, m(1, 1, [v(1, X)])).

ordina_m(List, Sorted) :- sort(2, @=<, List,  Sorted).

ordina_poly1(List, Sorted) :- sort(2, @>=, List,  Sorted).
ordina_poly2(List, Sorted) :- sort(3, @=<, List,  Sorted).

is_monomial(m(_C, TD, VPs)) :- integer(TD), TD >= 0, is_list(VPs).
is_polynomial(poly(M)) :- is_list(M), foreach(member(Monomio, M), is_monomial(Monomio)).

as_polynomial(+(X, Y), poly(C)) :- as_monomial(Y, G), as_polynomial(X, poly(Gs)), inverti(G, H), inverti2(Gs, Hs), ordina_poly2([H| Hs], D), inverti2(D, F), ordina_poly1(F, C), !.
as_polynomial(-(X, Y), poly(C)) :- as_monomial(-Y, G), as_polynomial(X, poly(Gs)), inverti(G, H), inverti2(Gs, Hs), ordina_poly2([H| Hs], D), inverti2(D, F), ordina_poly1(F, C), !.
as_polynomial(X, poly([X])) :- is_monomial(X), !.
as_polynomial(X, poly([Q])) :- as_monomial(X, Q), !.

/* grado massimo */
maxdegree(Poly1, Result) :- is_polynomial(Poly1), max_degree(Poly1, Result), !.
maxdegree(Poly1, Result) :- as_polynomial(Poly1, Result1), max_degree(Result1, Result), !.

max_degree(poly([]), 0) :- !.
max_degree(poly([m(_, X, _)|Xs]), X) :- max_degree(poly(Xs), Ys), X > Ys, !.
max_degree(poly([m(_, X, _)|Xs]), Ys) :- max_degree(poly(Xs), Ys), X =< Ys, !.

/* grado minimo */
mindegree(Poly1, Result) :- is_polynomial(Poly1), min_degree(Poly1, Result), !.
mindegree(Poly1, Result) :- as_polynomial(Poly1, Result1), min_degree(Result1, Result), !.

min_degree(poly([m(_, X, _)]), X) :- !.
min_degree(poly([m(_, X, _)|Xs]), X) :- min_degree(poly(Xs), Ys), X < Ys, !.
min_degree(poly([m(_, X, _)|Xs]), Ys) :- min_degree(poly(Xs), Ys), X >= Ys, !.

inverti(m(_, _, []), m(_, _, [])) :- !.
inverti(m(X, Y, [v(W, Z)| Xs]), m(X, Y, [v(Z, W)| Ys])) :- inverti(m(X, Y, Xs), m(X, Y, Ys)), !.

inverti2([], []) :- !.
inverti2([m(X, Y, [])| Zs], [m(X, Y, [])| Ss]) :- inverti2(Zs, Ss), !.
inverti2([m(X, Y, [v(W, Z)| Xs])| Zs], [m(X, Y, [v(Z, W)| Ys])| Ss]) :- inverti2([m(X, Y, Xs)| Zs], [m(X, Y, Ys)| Ss]), !.
```

I will not include code for as/is_polynomial cuz I already use it before and I don't have problem with that piece of code. Can you help me please?
An example for it, I tried, is maxdegree(x^5+y^500+4, R). (same thing for mindegree)

Comment: Since we don't have `is_polynomial` and `as_polynomial`, we can't run the code to see what's happening. In any case the problem almost certainly is on one of your four comparisons between `X` and `Ys`: one or both of those variables must be uninstantiated at one point. Finally, the fact that all your rules end with a cut almost certainly means that there is something deeply wrong with your code.

Comment: Do not look at the cuts. I know there are too many of them. I will put as/is_polynomial

Comment: We still miss `is_monomial`, and we also still don't know which predicate we are supposed to query to reproduce your problem.

Comment: [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Figure out what is the minimum amount of code you need to reproduce the error. You can use the [failure slice technique](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/failure-slice) to figure out what you can safely remove and still get the error instead of failing.

Comment: @Fatalize give me time man. My wi-fi is not so good ahahah

Comment: Still missing `inverti` and `inverti2`...

Comment: The arithmetic you are using: `=<` or `is`, is the "low hanging fruit" in your code at the moment.

Comment: @Boris you are right, I forget to put a piece of code. Give me time to do that. This is the "minimum" amount of code I can put on. My wifi is sock. I edit the new code like 10 minutes and the wifi puts it now

Comment: @Fatalize is already there. Can you see it?

Comment: You really should try to debug your code on your own first. Start with your top level query, look at the definition of the predicate you are calling, and start putting a `fail` systematically down the search tree until you get the instantiation error instead of a simple `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem adding a clausure in both maxdegree and mindegree as base case:

`max_degree(poly([m(_, _X, [])]), 0) :- !.
max_degree(poly([m(_, X, _)]), X).`

`min_degree(poly([m(_, _X, [])]), 0) :- !.
min_degree(poly([m(_, X, _)]), X) :- !.`